# How to animate and fill color in uiimageview in ios Swift Language?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, animation, uiimageview

Right now am doing Weather based application in ios swift language. In this, i have a requirement like animating sun from time bases. Like below mentioned images.

[image]

This sun is going to animate like this.

[image]

Refer this Video for animation: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0buw9k3m4v6b169/IMG_0146.m4v?dl=0

**Please give some reference links to do this kind of animation**.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is to create a `UIBezierPath` and make a `CAKeyFrameAnimation` follow it. Check [this link](https://maniacdev.com/2011/01/core-animation-defining-and-following-paths) for reference